# Search for the top-most appearance of tags with certain class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, nested, tags, findall

Suppose that a tag with certain class appear multiple times and are also nested with itself, how are you supposed to find the top-most appearance of each tag?

recursion=False wouldn't work because that only returns the top-level class.

For instance

```
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b' otherinfo='alpha'>
    <div class='lol'>
      <div class='b' otherinfo='bravo'></div>
  </div></div>
  <div class='b' otherinfo='charlie'>
    <div class='b' otherinfo='delta'></div>
  </div>
  <OTHER DIVS/>
</div>
```

In this instance, I want to find the top-most level (not first level) div with class 'b', but not the nested div under that div with class 'b'. I want the divs with otherinfo = 'alpha' and 'charlie' and not those with 'bravo' and 'delta'

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this code at work due to firewalls, but this should get you on the right track I believe (assuming your HTML is stored in the variable soup):

```
output = [] #list of top level div tags

class_b = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'b'})
for i in class_b:
    output.append(i.find_parent('div', {'class': 'b'}))
```

Those tags that append `None` to the list `output` will be the top-level div tags, therefore you could identify those instances with a nested if statement. Probably not the cleanest solution, but should work.